# Pyomo supported solvers on NEOS

Tags: optimization, python, gurobi, pyomo, neos

*Pyomo* has two solver managers to execute external solvers:

- `neos` (remote execution)
- `serial` (local execution).

```
pyomo help --solvers
```

yields **a list of solvers** available for each manager. It states

```
The following solver interfaces are available with YOUR CURRENT SYSTEM configuration: ...
```

**That list** does NOT contain `Gurobi` for the `neos` manager, which I want to use for my task.

Does it depend on my

> current system configuration

or is it a feature not implemented ? What configuration would be necessary ?

```
current system:

Pyomo 6.4.2 (CPython 3.9.13 on Windows 10)
Python 3.9.13
```

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to use Gurobi on the Neos is by using its web-based interface. Also, using Gurobi on the other AML needs to have a valid license.

Comment: Yes, with a valid license it is working locally. Probably a restriction from NEOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the interface on the NEOS server:

```
ampl: option solver kestrel;
ampl: option kestrel_options 'solver=gurobi';
ampl: option neos_server 'neos-server.org:3333';
ampl: option email 'USER@MAIL';
ampl: solve;
Connecting to: neos-server.org:3333
gurobi is not available on NEOS. Choose from:
    Bonmin
    Cbc
    CONOPT
    COUENNE
    CPLEX
    FilMINT
    filter 
    Ipopt
    KNITRO
    L-BFGS-B
    LANCELOT
    LGO
    LOQO
    MINLP
    MINOS
    MINTO
    MOSEK
    OCTERACT
    OOQP
    PATH
    RAPOSa
    SNOPT

To choose: option kestrel_options "solver=xxx";


exit value 1
<BREAK>
ampl:
```